# Why do I get this object when I query from MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

**guys I don't understand why I don't get my data from MongoDB. Instead, I get this object:**

```
   _mongooseOptions: {},
      mongooseCollection:
       NativeCollection {
         collection: null,
         opts: { bufferCommands: true, capped: false },
         name: 'products',
         collectionName: 'products',
         conn:
          NativeConnection {
            base: [Object],
            collections: [Object],
            models: [Object],
            config: [Object],
            replica: false,
..........
.....and so on
```

**This is my code:**

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Product = require('../models/product');

        router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
            var items = Product.find();
            console.log(items);

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Product.find()` returns a Query object. See the documentation here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html

To get the actual data, you must provide a callback:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  Product.find(function(err, items) { 
    console.log(items);
  });
});
```

You can see more examples of this in the official quick start: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/index.html

Comment: Thank you. It is working now.